# floating human on gas experiment

Tags: ideal-gas, density

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DzLX96VWTkc&feature=youtu.be
I saw this and now I' m wonder is it possible to make this gas to lift human . I read thread about making air dense as water and it is "possible" but the condition wouldn't be good for humans. So this could be better alternative for this kind of thing. Is it possible ? Is it harmless ? I would appreaciate long explenation :-)

Comment: That's what hot air balloons, blimps etc. do... we lift humans with a gas that is lighter than air. After all, a boat is also just a shape that reduces the average density of itself and its load enough to float on a liquid. If you wanted to float in a gas yourself,  water somewhere above the critical point may just do the trick. It would be a little hot, though, and the pressure would rather large.

Comment: I would like to trick gravity that we could be able to do things like in 0 gravity  but in this gas

Comment: @CuriousOne I think OP is looking for another thing. A gas heavy than air. Very heavy. So heavy, that it is more dense than us. And therefore, we lift on it. Just like in the video, the boat lifted. Hence, it should be cold, not hot.

Comment: It's a common misconception that floating in a gas (or liquid) is equivalent to zero gravity. Gravity does not differentiate between density differences and there is no differential pressure between the top and the bottom of an object in zero gravity, while it is this differential pressure that creates buoyancy for floating objects.

Comment: @Physicist137: I get what he is looking for, but I am not aware of such a substance at normal conditions. One can find such substances at more extreme thermodynamic conditions, though. I don't think even having such a substance would solve the OPs desire, though.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I agree. I look forward to read the answers.

Comment: It would be good for you to ask this question on chemistry SE too. I think they know many gasses. This is an interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to float a human in gas, the density of the gas must be greater than human density, which is about the same as water. For the human to be comfortable, this should be done somewhere near STP.

Given the ideal gas law can be written in terms of density as $\rho = PM/RT$, the only way to make a denser gas is to increase the molar mass, M. Since $M_{air} = 29$ and  water is 1000 times denser that air, we would need a gas with a molar mass around 29000.

While it is possible to make molecules that large (proteins are an example), they aren't ideal gasses at room temperature and pressure.

So your best bet is just to make the foil boat big enough to support a human.